# Rendering PartialView with table when clicking Search button

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Basically my question is regarding how to handle PartialView results.
My current (dummy) page is composed as follows:

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model SomeModel

@ {
    ViewBag.Title = "";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

...(Shortened code)
@using (Html.BeginForm ()) {
    @Html.EditorFor (model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Id", @type = "text" } })
    @Html.EditorFor (model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Name", @type = "text" } }) <
    <input type = "submit" value = "Search" / >
}

//The area where I want to place the PartialView result
<div class="row">
                @{Html.RenderAction("List", "Controller");}
</div>
```

**And then finally my List.cshtml**

```
@model SomeViewModel

<table class="table-bordered table table-hover m-2" id="table">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="align-middle">#</th>
            <th scope="col" class="align-middle">Field </th>
            <th scope="col" class="align-middle">Field </th>
            <th scope="col" class="align-middle">Field </th>
            <th scope="col" class="align-middle">Field </th>
            <th scope="col" class="align-middle">Field </th>
            <th scope="col" class="align-middle">Field </th>
            <th scope="col" class="align-middle">Field </th>
            <th scope="col" class="align-middle">Field </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
//A @foreach for each item in the model, with <td> tags
</tbody>
</table>
```

What I want is when I click the Search button in the Index.cshtml page, it should get the 2 fields used for search (Id and Name) and List the result in the same Page as a result of the List controller.

But what it's currently doing is when I click the Button it redirects me to /my/site/list which is just literally the result of List.cshtml, resulting in a unformatted page with just a table.

I've already tried the following code in the index.cshtml

```
<script>
    var url = '@Url.Action("List", "Controller")';
    $('form').submit(function() {
      if (!$(this).valid()) {
        return false;
      }
      var form = $(this).serialize();
      $('#list-items').load(url, form);
      return false; // prevent the default submit action
    })
</script>
```

But it just reloads the page without bringing anything, and the List Controller is never hit.

**List Action**

```
public ActionResult List(PIMPSearchViewModel search)
{
    var model = new PIMPListViewModel();
    using (var context = new dbBEMIEntities())
    {
        //TODO: 
        model.Pimps = context.tbPIMPs.Where(p => p.id_pimp == search.Id && 
                                                 p.service_type.Equals(search.SelectedServiceType, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                                                 p.status.Equals(search.SelectedStatus, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
        foreach (var item in model.Pimps)
        {
            item.status = context.tbParams.Where(k => k.key_complement == item.status).Select(k => k.param_value).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Comment: Hi Dwight.  Is there a reason you have to use that jquery script to submit?  If not, I would use the built-in MVC Ajax form.  Example to follow.

Comment: No there isn't, it's just one of the "answers" I found whilst browsing stack overflow. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is a particular reason to submit using jquery, I would use the built in Ajax.BeginForm helper.

First, change your form declaration to use ajax (notice the change from Html.BeginForm to Ajax.BeginForm...):

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("List", "Home",
      new AjaxOptions
      {
          InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
          HttpMethod = "POST",
          UpdateTargetId = "search-results"
      }))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Id", @type = "text" } })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Name", @type = "text" } }) 
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

So whats happening here is it will use ajax to submit the form, then when a result is returned, we are telling it to update a div with an id of "search-results" by replacing that div with the results.  In this case the results will be your partial view.  Also note we are specifying the controller and action in the form options.

Next change the div for the search results.  No need for the render call here because we dont need it until after the search:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="search-results"></div>
</div>
```

Notice the div id matches the ajax options UpdateTargetId.

Then in the post controller method, only change I would make it to specify the partial view name in the return.  Not sure if it is 100% needed, but I have run into trouble many times if I dont:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult List(Student model)
    {
        // Do stuff
        return PartialView("_myPartial", model);
    }
```

Last thing is to ensure you have the Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax nuget package installed and the script included in a bundle.  It is needed to make it ajaxy, otherwise the partial view will be returned as a full page.

UPDATE:

How to add script to a bundle.  Just add it to the jquery bundle.  Open the BundleConfig.cs file in the App_Start folder.  Find the jQuery bundle, which is usually the first one:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

And add a new line to include the unobtrusive ajax, so should look like this:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"));
```

Comment: Hi BattlFrog I'm really excited to try your alternative, but could you help me bundle the Unobtrusive ajax? My current code is             bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryunobtrusive-ajax").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax*")); the first parameter I just named the way I thought it'd be, is it correct? thanks

Comment: @Dwight I added bundling instructions to the answer.